# How can I upgrade apache in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: security, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running an Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS (Long Time Support), it comes with Apache/2.4.7.
However, Apache 2.4.10 is out, with [some security fixes](http://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html) I'd like to have.

So how can I get these security fixes, and still benefit the LTS provided by Ubuntu ? Does a manual install (from sources) will conflict with the unattended upgrades I've setup ?

What's the best way to keep my server up to date regarding security and maintainable on the long term (avoiding manual compilations / packages conflicts) ?

Comment: I would expect security fixes to be installed when running `apt-get dist-upgrade`. I am wondering if this question might get a more complete answer if it was migrated to askubuntu, that's not to say I consider it to be completely off-topic on serverfault.

Comment: Thanks @kasperd for your comment. I often run an `apt-get dist-upgrade`. Still, apache2 -v returns:
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 22 2014 14:36:38  : That's a month ago... decades when discussing security !

Comment: **sigh**... backports.  The answer is backports, it has been backports for a decade.  Subscribe to the security maillist for your distro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost every major Linux distro **backports** security patches.

From that article you can see the following CVE numbers and issues.

Fixed in Apache httpd 2.4.10

- important: mod_cgid denial of service CVE-2014-0231
- important: WinNT MPM denial of service CVE-2014-3523
- moderate: mod_proxy denial of service CVE-2014-0117
- moderate: mod_deflate denial of service CVE-2014-0118
- moderate: mod_status buffer overflow CVE-2014-0226

All you have to do is over on the [Ubuntu Security](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/) page and you will see [usn-2299-1](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2299-1/) which addresses all of them (except the 2014-3523, because Linux is not winnt).  So you need an Apache package version of at least `2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1`.  Which you should be able to get with a standard `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

> Does a manual install (from sources) will conflict with the unattended upgrades I've setup ?

Yes, very much, do not do that.  If you are going to install software directly from source, make sure you completely remove the packaged version first, or badness will happen.  Also, be certain that you will have ability and time to monitor all the appropriate vendor mail lists so you can maintain the packages yourself.

Comment: I'll follow your advises. Very precise answer, thanks for the explanations.

Comment: `dpkg -l apache2` displays `Version: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.1` so I can relax and go to bed :)

Comment: but what if I am not primary interested in security updates. For example tunneling of websockets is not working on 2.4.7 but on 2.4.16 is everything ok...